# Stable sorting in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting, dojo

I am using a dojo datagrid with `col1` as the column with primary sorting and `col2` as the secondary sorting column. After the grid loads if I again sort by `col1` by clicking on the header, I can see the order of the rows getting changed randomly where the `col1` has the similar values in **Google Chrome** . In **Firefox** everything seems to be working fine as they have stable sort implementation which maintains the original order of the input in case of similar key values. Is there a way I can implement some custom comparator for `Array.sort()` or something to avoid this problem in google chrome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show example & example code.

Comment: I think the problem is very clearly defined without code. "How can I do a stable sort in Chrome?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding one more column(hidden), the value of which is set to the index of the row, thus creating a column with a value which can uniquely identify any row and used this hidden column as one of the secondary sort column parameters in the dojo datagrid after the col1 and col2. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's already implemented. Give a chance to lodash function `_.sortBy`. It doing stable sort.

Here is docs: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy

Comment: This might be correct, but at this point of time, I had to do it without including any external library.